# Golang Migrate : How to specify version names like 1.1.1 etc.? Also, how to store history of migrations applied together?

Tags: go, migration, database-migration, migrate, golang-migrate

I am a beginner in Golang Migrate. I am trying to implement migration but have encountered the problem of naming my versions like 1.1.1. Currently, I can only name my version 1, 2, or 3 but not 1.1.1. So how do I name my versions in formats like 1.1.1, etc.?

Also, in Golang Migrate, we have 'schema_migrations' table which stores the latest migration version applied and not their history so I added 'schema_migrations_history' table. The rows get added in this history table when I am adding migration files one by one. But if I add 2 migration files together i.e. if I try to apply two or more versions of migrations together, then no row gets added to this history table.
I think this is because 'm.Up' checks all outstanding migrations and applies them together. But I want to add the history of these migrations.

Any solution to both these problems will be much appreciated.

My code:-
main.go ->

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"log"
"my-migrate-project/db"

"github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4"
_ "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/source/file"
)

const (
dbURL      = "postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/migrateDb?sslmode=disable"
dumpPath   = "C:/Users/91790/Documents/Otino/my-migrate-project/backups/"
dbName     = "migrateDb"
dbUsername = "postgres"
dbPassword = "password"

migrationsSource = "file://C:/Users/91790/Documents/Otino/my-migrate-project/db/migrations"
migrationsDir    = "db/migrations"
customQueriesDir1 = "db/migrations/custom_queries_1.sql"
customQueriesDir2 = "db/migrations/custom_queries_2.sql"
)

func main() {
sqlDB, err := db.OpenDB(dbURL)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error opening database connection:", err)
}
defer sqlDB.Close()

err = db.DumpDatabase(dbURL, dumpPath, dbUsername, dbPassword)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
}

m, err := migrate.New(migrationsSource, dbURL)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error creating migrate instance:", err)
}
defer m.Close()

isDirty, err := db.IsDatabaseDirty(sqlDB, m)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error checking if the database is dirty:", err)
    return
}

if isDirty {
    fmt.Println("Detected unexpected shutdown during migration. Rolling back...")
    if err := db.Rollback(sqlDB, m); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error during rollback:", err)
        return
    }

    _, err := sqlDB.Exec("UPDATE schema_migrations SET dirty=false")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error updating schema_migrations:", err)
        return
    }
    return
}

if err := db.BeforeMigrationTxns(sqlDB, customQueriesDir1); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error during transactions before migration:", err)

    if rollbackErr := db.Rollback(sqlDB, m); rollbackErr != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error during rollback:", rollbackErr)
    }
    return
}

if err := db.Migrate(sqlDB, migrationsDir); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error during migration:", err)

    if rollbackErr := db.Rollback(sqlDB, m); rollbackErr != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error during rollback:", rollbackErr)
    }
    return
} else {

    if err := db.AfterMigrationTxns(sqlDB, customQueriesDir2); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error during transactions after migration:", err)

        if rollbackErr := db.Rollback(sqlDB, m); rollbackErr != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error during rollback:", rollbackErr)
        }
        return
    }
}
fmt.Println("All operations completed successfully")
}
```

db.go ->

```
package db

import (
"bytes"
"database/sql"
"fmt"
"log"
"os"
"os/exec"
"path/filepath"
"time"

"github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4"
pgmigrate "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/database/postgres"
_ "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/source/file"
_ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func OpenDB(dbURL string) (*sql.DB, error) {
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", dbURL)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

return db, nil
}

func Migrate(sqlDB *sql.DB, migrationsDir string) error {
driver, err := pgmigrate.WithInstance(sqlDB, &pgmigrate.Config{})
if err != nil {
    return err
}

m, err := migrate.NewWithDatabaseInstance(
    "file://"+migrationsDir,
    "postgres", driver)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

if err := m.Up(); err != nil && err != migrate.ErrNoChange {
    return err
}

if err := UpdateMigrationHistory(sqlDB, m); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error updating migration history:", err)
    return err
}

fmt.Println("Migration successful")
return nil
}

func Rollback(sqlDB *sql.DB, m *migrate.Migrate) error {

var lastSuccessfulVersion uint
err := sqlDB.QueryRow("SELECT COALESCE(MAX(version), 0) FROM     schema_migrations_history").Scan(&lastSuccessfulVersion)
log.Println("last successful version: ", lastSuccessfulVersion)

if err != nil && err != sql.ErrNoRows {
    return fmt.Errorf("error getting last successful migration version: %w", err)
}

_, err = sqlDB.Exec("UPDATE schema_migrations SET version = $1, dirty = false", lastSuccessfulVersion)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("error updating schema_migrations table: %w", err)
}

log.Printf("Updated schema_migrations table: version = %d, dirty = false", lastSuccessfulVersion)

for {
    version, _, err := m.Version()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error getting current migration version: %w", err)
    }

    if version <= lastSuccessfulVersion {
        break // Stop rolling back once we reach the last successful migration
    }

    if err := m.Steps(-1); err != nil {
        if err == migrate.ErrNoChange {
            break // No more migrations to roll back
        }
        return fmt.Errorf("error rolling back migrations: %w", err)
    }
}

fmt.Println("Rollback successful")
return nil
}

func BeforeMigrationTxns(sqlDB *sql.DB, customQueriesDir1 string) error {
fmt.Println("Performing custom transactions before migration")

queries, err := readCustomQueries(customQueriesDir1)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

if _, err := sqlDB.Exec(string(queries)); err != nil {
    return err
}

return nil
}

func AfterMigrationTxns(sqlDB *sql.DB, customQueriesDir2 string) error {
fmt.Println("Performing custom transactions after migration")

queries, err := readCustomQueries(customQueriesDir2)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

if _, err := sqlDB.Exec(string(queries)); err != nil {
    return err
}

return nil
}

func readCustomQueries(queryFile string) ([]byte, error) {
queries, err := os.ReadFile(queryFile)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

return queries, nil
}

func RestoreDatabase(dbName string, backupPath string) error {
fmt.Println("Restoring database from backup")

cmd := exec.Command("pg_restore", "-d", dbName, "-U", "postgres", "-h", "localhost", backupPath)

cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

// Run the command
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("error restoring database from backup: %w", err)
}

fmt.Println("Database restored successfully")
return nil
}

func DumpDatabase(dbURL, dumpPath, dbUsername, dbPassword string) error {
dumpPath = dumpPath + "backup_" + time.Now().Format("2006-01-02T15_04_05") + ".dump"
fmt.Println("Taking database dump")

dumpDir := filepath.Dir(dumpPath)
if err := os.MkdirAll(dumpDir, os.ModePerm); err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("error creating dump directory: %w", err)
}

if _, err := os.Stat(dumpPath); os.IsNotExist(err) {
    file, err := os.Create(dumpPath)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error creating dump file: %w", err)
    }
    defer file.Close() 
}

cmd := exec.Command("pg_dump", "-U", dbUsername, "-p", "5432", "-F", "c", fmt.Sprintf("--file=%s", dumpPath), dbURL)
cmd.Env = []string{"PGPASSWORD=" + dbPassword}

var out bytes.Buffer
var stderr bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out
cmd.Stderr = &stderr

err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error in DumpDatabase: %s\n", err)
    fmt.Printf("stderr: %s\n", stderr.String())
    return err
}

fmt.Println("Dump successful")
return nil
}

func IsDatabaseDirty(sqlDB *sql.DB, m *migrate.Migrate) (bool, error) {
version, dirty, err := m.Version()

if version == 0 {
    return false, nil
} else if dirty {
    return dirty, nil
} else if err != nil {
    return false, err
}

return dirty, nil
}

func UpdateMigrationHistory(sqlDB *sql.DB, m *migrate.Migrate) error {
statements := `
BEGIN;

SET ROLE 'postgres';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schema_migrations_history (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    version BIGINT NOT NULL,
    applied_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION track_applied_migration()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE _current_version integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(version),0) FROM schema_migrations_history INTO _current_version;
    IF NEW.dirty = 'f' AND NEW.version > _current_version THEN
        INSERT INTO schema_migrations_history(version) VALUES (NEW.version);
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER track_applied_migrations
AFTER INSERT ON schema_migrations FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE track_applied_migration();

COMMIT;`

version, _, err := m.Version()
if err != nil {
    return err
}

if version == 1 {
    statements += "\nINSERT INTO schema_migrations_history(version) VALUES (1);"
}

_, err = sqlDB.Exec(statements)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("Error executing SQL statements:", err)
    return err
}

return nil
}
```

Comment: "how do I name my versions in formats like 1.1.1"; what lead you to believe this is supported? As per the [docs](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/blob/master/MIGRATIONS.md) "Versions of migrations may be represented as any 64 bit unsigned integer.".

Comment: For your other question ([one question per post please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735)) please provide a **minimal** sample. Currently it's a bit confusing; you appear to recreate the trigger after every migration so the trigger would not exist when the first migration is run (why not create the trigger as part of a migration?).

Comment: Okay, I see that we cannot have versions in the formats I want. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: For my second que (I am sorry for posting two que in one post, I'll remember this in future), I was thinking of creating a func that would add on rows automatically after migrating. I was hoping that this could be done by calling a func only. But if this is not possible in case of adding diff versions together, then I think we'll have to go with adding it in migration file itself.
Anyway, thanks for answering.

Comment: You could call a function but you would need to [Step](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4#Migrate.Steps) through the migrations one by one (doable but a bit more work).